# If x is between y and z, print, no output with python csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to get the first row of a csv to print when the condition is between the second and third row.

Here is my current code:

```
from libnmap.parser import NmapParser
import csv
from netaddr import *


ip = raw_input("Enter an IP: ")
addr = (int(IPAddress(ip)))

with open('DHCPranges.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:  
        if addr >= (int(IPAddress(row['start_address*'])) and addr <= (int(IPAddress(row['end_address*'])))):
            print (row['Network'])
```

When I input the IP, I don't get a print out. I have verified that the addr variable is working properly, so the if statement must be wrong somehow.

The csv is created like so, with commas:

```
Network,start_address*,end_address*
Matt's network,10.0.0.1,10.0.1.100
Chris's network,10.0.1.102,10.0.2.100
```

Comment: Have you checked what `row['start_address*']` looks like, and what `int(IPAddress(row['start_address*'])` end up being? Also, I think you meant "column" instead of "row" in your first sentence, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant column, but I have verified that the columns are printing out properly. As for the columns printing out, I used the statement print((row['Network'], int(IPAddress(row['start_address*'], int(IPAddress(row['end_address*'])))

Comment: @fedorqui It works when I have my current code and when I only print out the rows without the if statement logic.

Comment: You are casting an IP to `int`. I don't think this is going to work very well: `print int("123.123.123.123")` doesn't work, for example.

Comment: @fedorqui with the netaddr module, it casts IPs as an int

Answer (score 0):

You specify delimiter=',' but there are not comma delimeters in your file.  What is the actual delimiter?  Tab?  More than one space in the same place?

Try printing row.keys() in the loop, before the for line.  If the csv example is correct, it will give a single string.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a visual person, I used tabs when it should've been commas, I fixed it now. The row.keys() did work. I just a loop of my column names.